# Makefile --mingw32-make.exe

Tags: python, makefile

I have this makefile and I try to run it

```
code : CC = gcc

all: sph2pipe create_mix

sph2pipe: sph2pipe_compiled

sph2pipe_compiled: sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe

sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe: | sph2pipe_v2.5
    cd sph2pipe_v2.5/; \
    $(CC) -o sph2pipe  *.c -lm

sph2pipe_v2.5: sph2pipe_v2.5.tar.gz
    tar xzf sph2pipe_v2.5.tar.gz

create_mix:
    unzip create-speaker-mixtures.zip -d create-speaker-mixtures

clean:
    rm -rf sph2pipe_v2.5/
    rm -rf create-speaker-mixtures/
```

I'm on windows 8.1 so i use this commande in cmd : mingw32-make.exe makefile
but i have an error (( mingw32-make.exe nothing to be done for 'makefile' ))

I try to this : mingw32-make.exe
and i have another  error
i will share a picture with the second error
[image: the error n2]

Comment: Is that "code:" at the beginning really in your file, or are you just trying to say "this is my code"?  If that's really in there, you should delete it.  `CC = gcc` needs to start in column one, and by default `make` builds the first target that has a colon.  You want that to be `all`.

Answer (score 0):

Please cut and paste the commands you invoked and the errors you got into your question, and format it properly.  Other people with the same problems as yours cannot search a link to a picture on a remote site that may go away at any time and we can't copy content from an image.

However you say you ran the command:

```
mingw32-make.exe makefile
```

that is wrong.  Make doesn't accept the name of a makefile as an argument, it accepts the name of a target you want to build.  So this command is telling make, "please be sure the file `makefile` is up to date".  Since it is, you get the informative message (**not** an error!) telling you that.

You should just run:

```
mingw32-make.exe
```

and you may or may not get a different problem.